# @HystrixProperty cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: error-handling, spring-cloud, spring-tool-suite, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix

I have a method marked with @HystrixCommand that has a fallback method defined. I'm trying to add a hystrix property to it so that in case of a timeout it degrades gracefully into a fallback method.

But when I add the @HystrixProperty it shows an error in the STS IDE (3.8.2 Release) saying @HystrixProperty cannot be resolved to a type.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
    @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod="fallbackPerformOperation", 
                commandProperties={@HystrixProperty(name="execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds",value="5000")})
        public Future<Object> performOperation(String requestString) throws InterruptedException {  
    return new AsyncResult<Object>() {

                @Override
                public Object invoke() {.......
}}}
```

and this is the error being shown in the IDE:

[image: HystrixProperty Error]

I'm unable to figure out what the problem is.

Do I need to clear the STS Cache? If so how do I do it?

Thank You.

Comment: looks like the import statement for that type is missing or that type is not on the classpath of the project - in which case the error should show up on the import statement already.

Comment: `@HystrixCommand` and `@HystrixProperty` are both part of the `hystrix-javanica` artifact. Is that artifact on the classpath as a dependency?

Answer (score 4):

With in the IDE it is not obvious to suggest the import `HystrixProperty` class, thus you need to manually import this

```java
import com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.annotation.HystrixProperty;
```

Then the error should be gone